# building a Markov chain with spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, markov-chains

I'm working with a delta table containing log entries.  Is there anything in Spark (PySpark) that would help me build a Markov chain from certain events derived from this table?  If there aren't specific libraries for doing this, I would appreciate just an outline of a general direction of how to approach this problem (e.g. how to build in Spark a frequency matrix between adjacent events).